Should security roles ever negate or remove functionality or should they be additive only?
In my experience I believe that security roles in a software system where:

A user can have multiple roles and...
Roles can be included in groups (where groups are assigned to users)

...should only ever ADD functionality, never REMOVE or NEGATE functionality.
I'll elaborate by illustrating a counterpoint. Consider the following hypothetical roles:

Accounting
RemoteWorker

Let's assume the Accounting role gives you full access to accounting functionality where you can read data, edit data, run reports, etc.
In some code bases I've worked on, the security logic will limit the functionality as typically allowed by the Accounting role because of the existence of another assigned role such as the RemoteWorker role, limiting aspects to read only, or shutting off functionality in other ways.
This doesn't seem correct to me to have roles both add and remove functionality.
I believe that (in general) roles should be:

Additive in capability, not negate functionality otherwise available. In other words, if we need the ability for a user to be read only for Accounting, our roles might instead by sub-divided and look like this:

Accounting_Read
Accounting_Write


Not cover functionality provided by other roles. So instead of having a role such as Accounting which provides full accounting access and another role such as Payroll for a subset and AccountsReceivable (which are part of accounting), just have Payroll and AccountsReceivable role, and NOT an Accounting role and instead put these 2 roles in a group called "Accounting".

I know there are many ways to approach security, but first and foremost, my question is about whether or not there is a common and reasonable use case to say roles can and should negate functionality as well.
Bonus question about roles not covering functionality provided by other roles. That may be more opinionated.
